# What does “a lot of cargo for noodle soup" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar

An article in the issue of *The New York Times* dated March 4, 2014 introduces the phenomenon of New York City's proliferating ramen shops under the headline “Ramen’s big splash”.

It contains the following passage:

> “Rising like stream from these ceramic bowls is, in short, the city’s movement
>   from hushed fine dining to noisy eat-and-run joints; from subtle
>   flavors to assertive ones; from a dining scene in which pork played
>   almost no role to one in which it was the emperor of meats. **This is a
>   lot of cargo for noodle soup**. In the end, though, spinning theories
>   about ramen isn’t as much fun as tracking down a great bowl, so that‘s
>   what I’ve been doing lately.”

I don’t understand the meaning of the expression “This is a lot of cargo for noodle soup.” The *Concise Oxford Dictionary* (10th ed.) defines “cargo” simply as “goods carried commercially on a ship, aircraft or truck”.

What does “this” refer to, and what does “cargo” represent? According to the COD, “cargo” is a countable noun. Is “This is a lot of cargo” grammatically correct?

Comment: I'm far too tired to write an answer. I'll just note a line from *cargo* to *baggage* to *cultural baggage*.

Comment: The notion here is that the rise of ramen's status in the world of New York City foods can be taken as a metaphor for the rise of all fast-and-simple prepared foods from a previous tradition of carefully orchestrated meals at fine-dining establishments—and then the author acknowledges that such a role is quite a load for a simple noodle soup to carry. But of course, the soup didn't devise that exaggerated metaphor in the first place—the author did. So I blame him (or her).

Comment: That review's got a lot of cargo for such a simple thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“This is a lot of cargo” *is* grammatically correct. *Cargo* is both a countable noun and an uncountable noun, depending on the context. As a rule of thumb, a physical cargo is countable, and a metaphorical or abstract one isn't:

> (Countable:) *The ships had brought twenty-five full cargoes of wheat into the tiny port in the space of 36 hours.*
>
> (Uncountable:) *The metaphysical cargo embodied in the traditions of African tribal art that Picasso had observed as a young man influenced him long into his most productive years as a painter.*

In the context of the NYT piece you quoted, *This is a lot of cargo for noodle soup* means, in effect, "This represents a considerable range of culinary diversity and sophistication for [*implied:* something as humble as] noodle soup to have to carry".

In other words, this *range of diversity* is the soup's metaphorical *cargo*.

Comment: Yes. 'Represent' is a transitive verb that does not reuire preposition (for). I memorized "represent for" as an idiom for unknown reason (possibly cofused with 'account for), which was incorrect. I corrected it. Thank you for your pointing out.